# Login form menu item URL redirect not working

Tags: user, login, url

I have setup a default login form menu item that should redirect users to a specific menu item after logging in. Instead they are being redirected to the homepage.

The permissions on the login menu item are set to guest, so that it is hidden after login.

I have tested with Choose Login Redirect Type set to menu item and internal URL with both failing to work as expected. When using internal URL, I tried the format suggested in the input placeholder and with the component included in the URL like this: index.php?option=com_name&Itemid=2182 (abbreviated).

The user group being used for front-end login is registered.

I have cleared the cache in Joomla each time after making changes.

I have tested with and without template overrides in place for the login form default_login.php file.

When I try var_dump of the return variable attached to the redirect URL, the following is output:

- Menu item: string(4) "2089"
- Internal URL: string(58) "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2&Itemid=2089"

The website is running Joomla 4.4.1 with Admin Tools installed.

**Updated with further testing**

I am continuing to have this issue on my website with a custom template. I have completed the following testing and have included the results below:

I have completely disabled the custom overrides I had applied to com_users in the custom template's html directory. The overrides are not affecting how the after login redirect is handled.

I have set Cassiopeia as the default template style and set the login menu item to use the custom template. All of the other pages use Cassiopeia. When I login using the form, the redirect takes me to the proper profile page.

The user group for the login menu item is guest and registered for the profile menu item. The profile menu item is also hidden using the display in menu parameter in the menu item configuration.

I have completely disabled the login redirect by clearing the Menu Item Login Redirect parameter, but logged in users are still redirected to the homepage.

The site is using Membership Pro to handle subscriptions. I have tried disabling all Membership Pro related functionality, but the same redirect issues occur.

I have a logout menu item setup that correctly redirects logged out users to the menu item set in the item's configuration.

Debugging is enabled and the following is displayed in Session > Registry after successful login, but with incorrect redirection to homepage.

```
array:3 [
  "data" => array:1 [
    "users" => array:1 [
      "login" => array:1 [
        "form" => array:2 [
          "data" => []
          "return" => "https://dev.domain.com/"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "initialized" => false
  "separator" = > "."
]
```

The return url works sporadically. If I visit the login form menu item from the site's homepage, the login redirect return value is set to the homepage. If I visit the login form menu item after visiting other menu items like a single about article, the redirect url works correctly.

```
array:3 [
  "data" => array:1 [
    "users" => array:1 [
      "login" => array:1 [
        "form" => array:2 [
          "data" => []
          "return" => "index.php?Itemid=2182"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "initialized" => false
  "separator" = > "."
]
```

Caching is fully disabled on the website.

I hope someone can lend some assistance as users will probably be logging in directly from the homepage and need to be redirected to the set page and not returned to the homepage.

Cheers,

Comment: Do you have a login module published? It sounds like users are using the module and not the menu item to login.

Comment: @Sharky No, there are no Joomla login modules on the website.